# Create file for every result of find command?

Tags: files, find, filenames, exec

With this line of code I generate an output of every result.

```
exec("find ics/ -mmin +3 -type f -name '*.pdx' -exec basename {} ';' > ./tmp/filename")
```

How can I generate a file with dynamic file name everytime?
Like this:

```
./tmp/filename_{*Here should be the dynamic name*}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a new shell and provide the file as an argument. Then use POSIX parameter expansion to get rid of the path and —if desired—
the extension:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdx" \
  -exec sh -c \
    'base="${0##*/}"; printf "%s\n" "$base" > ./tmp/filename_"${base%.pdx}"' {} \;
```